Applying for UK Student Visa with a Recent Schengen Ban
I’m looking for some advice on my situation and hoping someone here can help.
Here’s my background:
In December 2018, I received a Schengen visa valid for 3 months. During that time, I traveled to Spain and overstayed my visa by 5 years. In May 2024, I decided to return to my home country, voluntarily; I wasn’t deported or required to leave, I just went back on my own. However, at the border control, Dutch border police issued me a 2-year ban from the Schengen Zone due to my overstay.
Now, I’ve received an unconditional offer from a university in the UK for a student visa. I’m hesitant about whether I should apply for the UK student visa right now or wait until the Schengen ban is lifted. My main concerns are:
Even though the UK doesn’t have direct access to SIS or SIS II, will UK visa officers be able to discover my Schengen ban or overstay?
If I apply for the UK student visa now without disclosing the Schengen ban or travel history to the Schengen area, how likely is it that UK visa officers will find out about it?
Will visa officers know about my travel history (last day i left and returned to my country ) even if i renewed my passport and has no issued visa or stamps?
If I wait for the 2-year period to end and apply for the UK student visa then, what’s the best approach for filling out the application? Should I mention the overstay and ban, or is it better not to disclose it?
For the International Travel History sectionin my VISA APPLICATION, should i list 3 months (the duration of the valid visa), or the 5 years I overstayed.

Trying to lie on a visa application in order to conceal another immigration violation is a great recipe for another ban.

You will be asked if you have ever been banned from entering any country or zone, and if you do not provide details of your Schengen ban, you will be using deception to enter the UK (10 year ban), and if the deception is discovered after you have entered, you can be removed at once.

As of now, the UK visa application forms, including those for a Tier 4 (Student) visa, do not explicitly contain a question that directly asks, "you have ever been banned from entering any country or zone?,I'm confused because i have never had any Deportations, Removals, or Refusals , i left on my own @MichaelHarvey

@kylianazirar Are you sure about that? IDK about student visa questions, but the UK Visitor visa definitely asks specifically about entry denials, visa refusals etc.  from any country. That section is in addition to the section on travel history.

As littleadv notes in a comment

Trying to lie on a visa application in order to conceal another immigration violation is a great recipe for another ban.

If you look around online, you will see that the UK can be quick to find deception in visa applications.  There is an automatic 10-year ban for using deception in a UK visa application under rule 9.8.1 of the Immigration Rules.  The question is not whether the UK can find out about your Schengen overstay and ban, but how certain you can be that they won't find out about it.  I doubt much certainty is possible.
I don't see any value in waiting for the ban to expire before applying.  The expiration of the ban doesn't make it much less likely for the UK to catch you if you lie on your application, and it doesn't change much about their assessment of the application if you tell the truth.
If you're really serious about wanting to go to this university and about wanting to maximize the chance of success of your visa application, hire a good immigration lawyer in the UK -- if you can afford it.  The visa officer is going to take your travel history as an indication of your willingness to ignore immigration laws.  It will be difficult to overcome that.
The alternative is to risk not going to the UK until sometime in the 2030s, if ever.  (Once the ban expires, UK visa officers will view any subsequent applications with skepticism and will tend to discount the credibility of any statements you make, so you may never succeed in obtaining a UK visa.)  Is that a consequence that you're prepared to live with?

(+1) This example of the online application form has a section on Immigration history. I’m not convinced the OP’s assertion in a comment that the UK doesn’t ask about bans is correct.
